# Settings activity up button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, up-button

I have a `SettingsActivity` that should have an up button linking back to `MainActivity`. The button appears, but doesn't do anything when clicked. The back button works fine.

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

I tried adding an action to `onOptionsItemSelected` for `R.id.home` with no luck. I also tried adding `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` to `onCreate()`, but it crashes the app with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)'
```

Comment: and have you tried `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` ?

Comment: Please read the full question ;)

Comment: Yes I've already read it bro, and I am talking about `getSupportActionBar()` ?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have tried both. support action doesn't work, but doesn't crash.

Comment: Sometime it's also needed to make that work, `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`. Try putting the above and this both statement.

Comment: Using both support action bar and action bar? Still crashes… What exactly are you saying I should try?

Comment: No, don't use `getActionBar()`. It is sure that you are using support library, So that I am saying you to put these both statement 
`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
`getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: I get it. No, still doesn't go back to `MainActivity` and nothing shows in the console.

Comment: If that also didn't work then final option is to use the app icon to get back 
`getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Comment: The app currently doesn't have an icon, but I switched it for a different drawable, and nothing. The button registers a press, but it goes nowhere.

Comment: I think you have cleared up the previous statement and put only `setHomeAsUpIndicator`. Don't remove them put all, and only after that try switching by removing unused one.

Comment: Nope, i tried different combinations of all the methods I've tried. Nothing changes regardless.

Comment: how you extending your class AppcompatActivity or AppCompatPreferenceActivity ???

Comment: `SettingsActivity` extends `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`, which was automatically generated by Android Studio's New > Settings Activity menu option.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose your code base was generated by Android Studio because I met the same problem. You can add the following code into your SettingsActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish(); // or go to another activity
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This will make sure the up button works.